# Huge SQL query on 4 tables and multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

First table : `products_categories (category_id, category_infos…)`

Second table : `products_categories_relations (product_id, category_id)`

Third table : `slave_products (master_product_id, published, product_logistics…)`

Fourth table : `master_products (product_id, published, product_stock…)`

I want to get all empty categories. A category could be defined as empty if it respects this combination of conditions :

- no products in them
- no published products in master table and then in slave table (if a product is unpublished in master but published in slave, it's not published. Master is always right.)
- product_stock in master in 0, but except if product_logistics in slave is 0 too. If products_logistics in slave is 1, we don't care about the stock…

Example :

if a category contains 100 products but 50 are unpublished in master and 30 more are unpublished in slave and the stock in master is 0 for the last 20 of these items as the logistics options are 0 for these ones… it's empty !

I tried it in a lot of different ways and can't find a formula which could combine every conditions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for and you can add additional "OR" statements to the second query if there are variables I'm missing:

```
SELECT products_categories.*
WHERE products_categories.category_id NOT IN 
(
SELECT distinct category_id from products_categories_relations
)
OR products_categories.category_id NOT IN
(
SELECT distinct products_categories.category_id 
FROM products_categories
INNER JOIN products_categories_relations pcr ON prc.category_id = products_categories.category_id
INNER JOIN master_products master ON master.product_id = pcr.product_id
INNER JOIN slave_products slav on slav.master_product_id = master.product_id
WHERE master.published = 0
OR (master.product_stock = 0 AND slav.product_logistics = 0)
)
```

Comment: It was not exactly the right way to do the query, but the structure itself was exactly what i missed ;) Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can make 3 queries each satisfying one of the conditions above then join the queries together.
Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
Query 1 AS Q1,Query 2 AS Q2, Query 2 AS Q3
WHERE Q1.category_id=  Q2.category_id AND ...
```